# How do I set the order of a Grid using GUI Layout Toolbox for MatLab?

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I'm trying to create a simple grid for a GUI within MatLab where I want a static text and then an editable box as an input like so:

```
+-----------------------+---------------+
|   Name 1   (1)        |  Input 1   (2)|
|                       |               |
+-----------------------+---------------+
|   Name 2   (1)        |  Input 2   (2)|
|                       |               |
+-----------------------+---------------+
```

I'm using the [Grid class](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27758-gui-layout-toolbox/content/GUILayout-v1p13/+uiextras/Grid.m) from the [GUI Layout Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27758-gui-layout-toolbox) with the following code:

```
    % Parameters Section:
    staticPropPanel = uiextras.BoxPanel('Parent', paramPanel, 'Title', 'Signal Properties:');
    sPropGrid = uiextras.Grid('Parent', staticPropPanel, 'Spacing', 5);

    uicontrol('Style', 'text', 'Parent', sPropGrid, 'String', 'Number of Samples');
    nSamples = uicontrol('Style', 'edit', 'Parent', sPropGrid);
    uicontrol('Style', 'text', 'Parent', sPropGrid, 'String', 'Sampling Frequency (Fs) in Hz');
    Fs = uicontrol('Style', 'edit', 'Parent', sPropGrid);
    uicontrol('Style', 'text', 'Parent', sPropGrid, 'String', 'Carrier Frequency (Fc) in Hz');
    Fc = uicontrol('Style', 'edit', 'Parent', sPropGrid);

    set(sPropGrid, 'ColumnSizes', [-3 -1], 'RowSizes', [25 25 25]);
```

However the grid isn't properly adding the elements in the correct order after the 'resizing' of the grid.  For example, before `set(sPropGrid, 'ColumnSizes', [-3 -1], 'RowSizes', [25 25 25]);` is executed I get the following:

[image: Grid before resize]

However **after** the resizing is done, I get the following:

[image: Grid after resize]

How do I alter the order of the resize so that right elements are placed in the correct position?

Comment: Is resizing fundamental? Before getting into resizing issues (quite a pain!), I would code the GUI completely and then decide on such additional functionality.

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow what you mean by 'is resizing fundamental?'.  If what you're asking is whether or not I need for the elements to be divided into two columns, and each row to be the same (text, edit box), then yes this is necessary.

Comment: What I mean is, do you need the layout to be resizeable? If not, you can code it to be statically fixed width/height.

Comment: @OlegKomarov the beauty of using GUI Layout Toolbox is that I don't have to statically set the width and height of every box I add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the documentation that comes with the GUI Layout Toolbox, you'll see the following example:

```
f = figure();
g = uiextras.Grid( 'Parent', f, 'Spacing', 5 );
uicontrol( 'Parent', g, 'Background', 'r' )
uicontrol( 'Parent', g, 'Background', 'b' )
uicontrol( 'Parent', g, 'Background', 'g' )
uiextras.Empty( 'Parent', g )
uicontrol( 'Parent', g, 'Background', 'c' )
uicontrol( 'Parent', g, 'Background', 'y' )
set( g, 'ColumnSizes', [-1 100 -2], 'RowSizes', [-1 100] );
```

which produces the following figure:

[image: Grid from documentation]

You'll see that objects are added by rows first and then by columns (red (1,1), blue (2,1), green (1,2), empty(2,2), etc,.)  So in your case, you need to add all of the `uictonrols.text` first and then the `uicontrols.edit`.

Comment: That's right - the elements are put into the grid in the order that you create them (or rather, the order that you set them to be a child of the grid). You then set the `ColumnSizes` and `RowSizes` property of the grid (which has to give the right number of elements), and the elements are then displayed in column-major order. Hope you're enjoying GUI Layout Toolbox :)

Comment: @SamRoberts I am actually.  It's super powerful and easy to use.